# image not displaying in navbar correctly, rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a logo to the left side of my navbar (which would also function as a link to the home page) however, it only displays as a "?" in a box. Any tips on fixing this?

here is the code for the navbar...

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
       <img  alt="Brand"  src="/assets/images/1.png">
     </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the asset pipeline and `image_tag` helper.

```
# image location
# app/assets/images/1.png

# view
<%= image_tag("1.png", alt: "Brand") %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Once you do this, right click on the image and inspect the element. Check out the new src of the image. It should be something like this:

```
/assets/1-71eb0fe483901ef632b3136926dd70ce3954e7cb6e97baa1bd53d197c38653d0.png
```

That is why you are unable to use the relative path to the image! It doesn't exist! Something to consider: Rails is very powerful, with a ton of incredibly useful built in features. Let it do the heavy lifting.

Again, it's worthwhile to read this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html